# Uncaught Reference Error: [X] is not defined. Only when compilation debug=true

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, web-config, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I updated a few libraries and code and published an update to our production environment. There was a JavaScript error which only occurred in production environment and not in our dev and test environments.

After going through every possibility, I discovered that if I change **compilation debug="false"** to **debug="true"** (in web.config) then everything works in all environments.

Likewise, when I changed the setting from **true** to **false** in any environment, the controls doesn't work. I've restarted IIS on all servers and even rebooted the test environment web server, but the scripts still doesn't load when debug is set to false in any environment.

I believe the WebResources.AXD call is being cached, so I've cleared my browser cache (multiple times) and set my Chrome dev tools to disable caching. However, even after a test env server reboot, the script fails to be properly loaded when debug is set to true.

It continues to work fine in all environments when debug is set to true and continues to fail in all environments when debug is set to false. For the time being, I reverted my production environment, so I'm just trying to get it to work in the dev & test environment with debugging=true, before trying to publish it to production again.

Using MS IIS 6, ASP.NET 4x, Win 2003R2 servers

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sorta strange, but I found the answer to my question.

I added **CombineScripts="false"** to my ToolkitScriptManager tag and everything seems to work now when using debug=true or debug=false.